# Qt: How to check from C++ whether an object is of QML type Foo

Tags: c++, qt, types, qml

Consider a QML type (defined in QML, not in C++):

```
Foo {
}
```

And assume I have a `QQuickItem* item` variable in C++. **How do I check if the variable is of type Foo?**

If Foo was a C++ type, I could do this:

```
qobject_cast<Foo*>(item) == nullptr
```

Since Foo is a QML type, one option would be

```
item->metaObject()->className().beginsWith("Foo")
```

(`className()` returns something like `Foo_QMLTYPE_0`)

But that seems unreliable and hacky.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a magic key property:

```
Foo {
  property bool isFoo : true
}
```

And then from C++:

```
if (obj->property("isFoo").toBool())
```

If the object doesn't have that property, then the condition should fail. This will also work for "derived" objects as the property will be "inherited", for example if something extends `Foo` but is not necessarily named `FooSomething` but rather `SomethingFoo`.

Naturally, there will be some overhead, which could get pronounced in scenarios where you need a lot of type checks on many instances. What I tend to do is have a single `quint32 type` property implemented efficiently on C++ level, then from QML this is explicitly set in objects where type information is necessary. This way the overhead is minimized, and it is also faster to access than using `property(name)`.

Comment: I advice to use `objectName` as a magic key. In this case you can access it by `obj->objectName` and also will be able to use `rootItem->findChild<QQuickItem*>("myObjectName")` to find the item.

Comment: @ddriver: Thanks, yeah, I'm using your `isFoo` solution currently, I'd prefer something cleaner though. I do like that it works for "derived" objects too. Also useful note about overhead, though in my case that's not a problem.

Comment: @folibis: `objectName` works if I only want to find one object. I want to find a bunch of items that have the same type.

Comment: @StefanMonov, you're wrong. I've adviced that because I use it in my own applications. You can easy find list of objects by `objectName`, for example: `QList<QQuickItem *> list = item->findChildren<QQuickItem *>("Rectangle");` where Rectangle is a `objectName` set for several items. Anyway, in general that's already the same as @ddriver solution. But you already have ready helper function.

Comment: @folibis: Oh, I didn't know that. Thanks. I still won't use that though, because it's confusing - I'd expect an `objectName` to be unique in a context, just like an `id` is.

Comment: That's an option too. I am kind of an efficiency freak because my project deals with very high object counts and qml is a memory hog. I don't even use strings for object names, I use an integer id, which leads to a dictionary of ref counted phrases, which are consisted of a list of intenger ids, which lead to a dictionary of ref counted words, in order to share every repeating word and phrase, with those being used to reconstruct the actual string only when its needed :D

Answer (score 0):

IMO you are part of the way there. Your best bet is using a combination of `QQuickItem::inherits` and `QMetaObject::className`.

This way you can figure out if it is actually a `Foo` or derived from `Foo`.

```
const QByteArray foo = QByteArrayLiteral("Foo");

if (item->metaObject()->className() == foo || item->inherits(foo)) {
    // It's a Foo
}
```

Comment: As I wrote in the question, `className()` returns something like "Foo_QMLTYPE_0", not "Foo", so unfortunately that doesn't work.